# ¿Como y cuando se usan isset() y empty() correctamente?

Tags: php, funciones, condiciones

He visto en muchas ocasiones al recibir los datos de un formulario la siguiente comprobación:

```
if (isset($_POST['campo1'])) {
   // Resto de código
}
```

¿Qué pasa si el valor `$_POST['campo1']` está vacío?

---

O en muchas otras ocasiones he visto la siguiente comprobación:

```
if (isset($_POST['campo1']) && !empty($_POST['campo1'])) {
   // Resto de código
}
```

Es completamente redundante de comprobar el valor `$_POST['campo1']` al mismo tiempo con `isset()` y `!empty()`?

---

Entonces mi pregunta es: ¿cómo y cuándo se usan `isset()` y `empty()` correctamente?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Según la documentación de [isset()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php):

> Devuelve `true` si la variable existe y tiene un valor distinto de
>   `null`, `false` de lo contrario.

Por ejemplo:

```
$var = ''; // Cadena vacía

if (isset($var)) { // <= true
    ... 
}
```

Siempre te va a volver `true` aunque la la variable este vacía y se debería de comprobar con la función `empty()`:

```
$var = ''; // Cadena vacía

if (!empty($var)) { // <= false

    // No está vacía (true)

} else {

    // Está vacía (false)
}
```

*¿Y cuando deberías usar `isset()`?*

Siempre y cuando que quieras comprobar que la variable existe, un ejemplo bueno sería si quieres saber si se ha *mandado* un formulario:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    ...
    <input type="text" name="campo1" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar formulario">
</form>

if (isset($_POST['submit']) {
  ...
}
```

---

Según la documentación de [empty()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php):

> Devuelve `false` si la variable existe y tiene un valor no vacío,
>   distinto de cero. De otro modo devuelve `true`.

Con `empty()` las siguientes expresiones son consideradas como vacías (**empty**) y devuelven `true`:

```
"" (una cadena vacía)
0 (0 como un integer)
0.0 (0 como un float)
"0" (0 como un string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (un array vacío)
$var; (una variable declarada, pero sin un valor)
```

**Importante** de saber, que no se genera una advertencia si la variable no existe.

Esto significa que `empty()` es esencialmente el equivalente conciso de:

`!isset($var) || $var == false`.

Entonces si quedaría redundante si comprobamos la *misma* variable con `isset()` y `empty()` al mismo tiempo.

Un ejemplo como se puede usar `isset()` y `!empty()` al *mismo* tiempo cuando se quiere recibir los datos de un formulario:

```
<form method="post" action="">    
    <input type="text" name="campo1" value="">
    ...
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar formulario">
</form>

if (isset($_POST['submit']) {

    if (!empty($_POST['campo1'])) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Isset**

Isset lo usas cuando quieres saber

> si una variable está definida y no es NULL..

Ejemplo, **archivo1.php**

```
 if ( isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
      // Acciones
    }
```

Esto puede ser útil si quieres validar que un archivo reciba variables POST, ya que podrías acceder por *url* *localhost/mifolder/archivo1.php*, si accedes así no estás enviando ningún valor por POST, entonces no entra al If.

Otro ejemplo:

```
$var = '';

// Esto evaluará a TRUE así que el texto se imprimirá.
if (isset($var)) {
    echo "Esta variable está definida, así que se imprimirá";
}
```

Fuente: [documentación isset](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php)

**Empty**

Empty es para saber si una variable está vacía.

> "Una variable se considera vacía si no existe o si su valor es igual a
>   FALSE. empty() no genera una advertencia si la variable no existe."

```
$var = 0;

// Se evalúa a true ya que $var está vacia
if (empty($var)) {
    echo '$var es o bien 0, vacía, o no se encuentra definida en absoluto';
}
```

Lo que PHP considera como empty:

- "" (una cadena vacía)
- 0 (0 como un integer)
- 0.0 (0 como un float)
- "0" (0 como un string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (un array vacío)
- $var; (una variable declarada, pero sin un valor)

Fuente: [documentación de empty](http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php)

**¿Es redundante usar isset junto empty?**

No, ya que puede haber una variable definida pero cuyo valor sea 0, entonces es necesario evaluar primero que no sea null, y si no es null evaluar que no esté vacía **en el caso de que quieras devolver un mensaje al usuario** indicando que debe ingresar un valor o si lo ingresó, indicarle que no puede ser 0 o un espacio, por decir dos ejemplos (el formato en general).

```
$var = 0;

if (isset($var))
  echo 'La variable está definida';

if (empty($var))
  echo 'La variable está definida pero está vacía';
```

**Conclusión:** isset y empty evalúan una variable de manera **diferente**. Isset si una variable es null, empty si está vacía pudiendo ser NULL o cualquiera de la lista anterior.

Comment: Entonces si es redundante...si `empty()` retorna false si no existe la variable... Mira mi respuesta: `empty()` es esencialmente el equivalente conciso de: `!isset($var) || $var == false`

Comment: Por eso coloqué entre negritas que es útil cuando quieres dar un mensaje al usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Exelente en el index  puedes tambien utilizar esta forma utilizando dos sentencias:

```
if (isset($_POST['$var1']) && !empty($_POST['$var1']) && (isset($_POST['$var2']) && !empty($_POST['$var2']))) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);


        require_once "conexion.php";
            require_once "buscar.php";
}
```