# Evitar que php envíe las variables vacías a MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este script sencillo:

```
<form action="inc/post/proccess.php" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="username">
   <input type="text" name="profesion">
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

proccess.php

```
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pro = $_POST['profesion'];
$query ="UPDATE tbl_user SET name = '$user',profesion = '$pro' WHERE tbl_user.id =7";
$inserted_rows = mysql_query($query);
```

Cuando actualizo solamente el nombre de usuario, la variable `$pro` se envía vacía y directamente me lo guarda en MySQL. ¿Como puedo evitarlo?

Comment: Esto te va a servir: [link](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32133/como-y-cuando-se-usan-isset-y-empty-correctamente)

Comment: ¿qué es lo que debe ocurrir cuando va vacía?

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo un ejemplo (del comentario que te he dejado) de como se podría validar los valores que recibes del formulario.

Primero comprobaría si el formulario fue enviado, para eso tendrías que añadir el atributo `name` en tu `<input type="submit" ... >`.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
```

Y ahora podrías hacer la comprobación de la siguiente manera:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Comprobar si se envío el formulario

    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pro = $_POST['profesion'];

     // Comprobar que ninguno de los campos estén vacíos
    if (!empty($user) && !empty($pro)) {

        $query ="UPDATE tbl_user SET name = '$user',profesion = '$pro' WHERE tbl_user.id =7";
        $inserted_rows = mysql_query($query);

    } // Si quieres pones un else para mostrar un mensaje de error o notificación
}
```

Y ya que estás aprendiendo todo esto te recomiendo urgentemente que aprendas [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) o mejor aún [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) con sentencias preparadas para evitar ataques de [inyecciones SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Answer (score 1):

Podrías validarlas desde PHP, algo así como:

```
if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
    $emailErr = "username is required";
} else {
    $email = test_input($_POST['username']);
}
```