# Diferencias entre usar !empty o !== ""

Tags: php, validación

Cual seria la diferencia entre validar de estados dos formas:

```
if(!empty($_POST['miName']{
}

if($_POST['miName'] !== ""{
}
```

Comment: en este hilo se explica https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32133/como-y-cuando-se-usan-isset-y-empty-correctamente

Answer (score 0):

En que con ***empty*** puede **abarcar** esto:

- "" (una cadena vacía)
- 0 (0 como un integer)
- 0.0 (0 como un float)
- "0" (0 como un string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (un array vacío)
- $var; (una variable declarada, pero sin un valor)

Citando la respuesta de @J.Correa en la publicación [¿Como y cuando se usan isset() y empty() correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32133/como-y-cuando-se-usan-isset-y-empty-correctamente)

Y con **!== ""** está comparando estrictamente ambos lados para su VALOR y TIPO. El resultado será verdadero si VALOR o TIPO es inconsistente, en el cual estará validando si en _$POST hay una cadena vacía