# Php insert undefined

Tags: php, insert, undefined

Hola he buscado en foros pero no he podido hallar la solución. Estoy tratando de ingresar registros.

```
<div align="center">
    <form action="cliente_ingresado.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="identificacion" >Identificación:  </label> &nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="identificacion" id="identificacion" required="required"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="nombre" >Nombre: </label>&nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required="required"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="direccion">Dirección: </label>&nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="telefono">Teléfono: </label>&nbsp;
        <input type="text" id="telefono" name="telefono"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="correo">Correo: </label>&nbsp;
        <input type="email" id="correo" name="correo"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="sexo">Sexo: </label>&nbsp;
        <input type="text" id="sexo" name="sexo"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="estado_civil">Estado Civil:  </label>&nbsp;
        <input type="text" id="estado_civil" name="estado_civil"/>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Guardar</button> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;


        <button type="button">Limpiar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Aquí proceso:

```
echo $_POST['identificación'];
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {
        $identificacion = $_POST['identificación'];
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
        $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
        $correo = $_POST['correo'];
        $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
        $estadoCivil = $_POST['estadoCivil'];

        $insertar = "INSERT INTO tbl_clientes (identificacion, nombre, direccion, telefono, correo, sexo, estado_civil) VALUES ('$identificacion', '$nombre', '$direccion', '$telefono', '$correo', '$sexo', '$estado_civil')";

        $ejecutar = mysqli_query($con, $insertar);

        echo $ejecutar;
        if($ejecutar)
        {
            echo "Insertado correctamente";
        }
        else 
            {
                echo "Error";
            }

        mysqli_close($con);

    }
    else
    {
        echo "Insert no definido";
    }
```

Pero me dice que es undefined

Comment: Hola. ¿Dónde o qué te dice que es undefined?

Comment: te dice "Insert no definido" porque está pasando al else directamente  ` echo "Insert no definido";` ,eso  quiere decir que `(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit']))` siempre es false, así que nunca va a intentar hacer el query a mysqli y todo lo que está adentro del if... Intenta validar lo que está llegando a  `$_POST['submit']`

Comment: Al inicio, es que puse una variable afuera a ver que pasaba... Undefined index, qué cambios debería hacer?

Comment: has echos y muestra donde no llegan tus variables

Comment: Te recomiendo pasar revisar esta publicación [Revisar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32133/como-y-cuando-se-usan-isset-y-empty-correctamente), ademas debes de verificar las coincidencias de las variables que defines en el formulario y en como las recibes por `$_POST[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verificar:

- Las variables $_POST[""] que reciba sean iguales a las declarada en su formulario.
- Evitar el uso de acentos en variables.

**isset()**

> Determina si una variable está definida y no es NULL

**empty()**

> Determina si una variable es considerada vacía. Una variable se
>   considera vacía si no existe o si su valor es igual a FALSE. empty()
>   no genera una advertencia si la variable no existe.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (!empty($_POST['identificacion']) && !empty($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['direccion']) &&
        !empty($_POST['telefono']) && !empty($_POST['correo']) && !empty($_POST['sexo']) && !empty($_POST['estado_civil'])) {

        $identificacion = $_POST['identificacion'];
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
        $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
        $correo = $_POST['correo'];
        $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
        $estadoCivil = $_POST['estado_civil'];

        $insertar = "INSERT INTO tbl_clientes (identificacion, nombre, direccion, telefono, correo, sexo, estado_civil) VALUES ('$identificacion', '$nombre', '$direccion', '$telefono', '$correo', '$sexo', '$estado_civil')";

        $ejecutar = mysqli_query($con, $insertar);

        if($ejecutar){
            echo "Insertado correctamente";
        }else {
                echo "Error";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Datos vacios.";
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
    }else{
        echo "Insert no definido";
    }
```

Recomendaciones:

> Uso de isset() y empty() -
>   [Publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32133/como-y-cuando-se-usan-isset-y-empty-correctamente)
>
> Como evitar la inyeccion SQL -
>   [Publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: undefined index en esta línea $identificacion = $_POST['identificación'];

Comment: Probaste el codigo que te proporcione?, el error que tenias era por el acento en  `$_POST['identificación']`

Comment: Tenías razón, lo corregí y funciona. Gracias Palacio

Comment: De nada, si te ayudo la respuesta la puedes marcar como aceptada. [Que hacer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Cómo? como la marco aceptada?

Comment: Dando clic en el la palomita [Ejemplo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas)

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que el error está en $_POST['submit'], ahí no llega una variable simplemente es el botón de enviar, entonces al no llegar la variable siempre será marcado como false.

Comment: Hice los cambios... ahora sale Undefined index: linea 80

Comment: if(isset($_POST['identificacion']) &&
   isset($_POST['nombre']) && 
   isset($_POST['direccion']) && 
   isset($_POST['telefono']) && 
   isset($_POST['correo']) &&
   isset($_POST['sexo']) &&
   isset($_POST['estado_civil'])) 
  {
   $identificacion = $_POST['identificación']; Aquí sale el error

Answer (score 0):

creo que deberias preguntar si estan seteadas las cajas de tu formulario en vez de hacer 'isset($_POST['submit'])'

```
if(isset($_POST['direccion']) && isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['direccion']))
{
    //tu codigo...
}
```

ademas creo que deberias cambiar en tu codigo php:

```
$_POST['estadoCivil'] por $_POST['estado_civil']
```

ya que en tu formulario el name que tiene el input es ***estado_civil*** y no ***estadoCivil***

Comment: Aún con los cambios sigue saliendo el error

Comment: Gracias a todos, hice las correcciones y funciona