# Problema login y direccionamiento con php

Tags: php, login

mi problema es que al momento de ingresar al login(con los datos correctos) me redirige de nuevo al index del login para entrar, y cuando modifico el header(location: index1.php)  me envia al index1 que es el que quiero pero no me deja ingresar a la pagina y me dice que se redirecciona demasiadas veces aca les dejo el codigo si me pueden ayudar

```
    <?php

require('conexion.php');

//-----------------------------------este es el index del login

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

if(!empty($_POST))
{
    // asigno a las variables los valores ingresados por teclado

    $usuario = htmlentities($_POST['usuario']); 

    // htmlentities --> funcion de php evita ataques xss (xss son codigos javascript y html) 
    // un ejemplo seria = <script>alert("hola");</script>

    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['usuario']);

    // mysqli_real_escape_string --> funcion de php evita ataques sql injection (inyecciones de sentencias sql)
    // un ejemplo seria =  'or'1'=1


    $password = htmlentities($_POST['password']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['password']);


    // mysqli_real_escape_string es una metodo de php para evitar ejecucion de inyeccion sql
    // atravez de ingreso de carateres especiales por ej. ...coma ... comilla simple ... comilla doble
    // este metodo limpia esos caracteres especiales

    $error = '';

    //sha1 --> metodo que encripta la contraseña para consultarlo con la base datos 
    $sha1_pass = sha1($password);

    //consulta sql  
    $sql = "SELECT id, id_tipo FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND password = '$sha1_pass'";
    // ejecuto la consulta
    $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
    // obtengo la cantidad de registros en la tabla usuarios 
    $rows = $result->num_rows;

    // si existe el usuario y la contraseña     
    if($rows > 0) {

        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

        // les asigno a las variables de sesion los valores obtenidos de la base datos

        $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] = $row['id_tipo'];

        // nos envia a pagina de bienvenida index1.php

        header("location: index1.php");

        } else {
        // sino nos muestra este mensaje
        $error = "El nombre usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos";
        }
    }
?>



    <?php

//---------------- esta es la parte de index1

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
    header("Location: index1.php");
}

//-------------------------------------------

    require 'conexion.php';

    $idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
    $sql = "SELECT u.id, p.nombre FROM usuarios AS u INNER JOIN personal AS p ON u.id_personal=p.id WHERE u.id = '$idUsuario'"; 
    $result=$mysqli->query($sql);   
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
?>
```

si me pueden ayudar se los agradeceria

Comment: Porque redireccionas en index1.php cuando no encuentras en la $_SESSION los datos del usuario para la misma página, no deberia ser para la de login????

Comment: La pagina donde haces esta comprobación: if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){ header("Location: index1.php"); } cual es??????

Answer (score 2):

El problema esta en:

```
if( !isset( $_SESSION["id_usuario"] ) ){
    header("Location: index1.php");
}
```

El `isset()` comprueba si existe y/o esta creado, en este caso existe porque supongo que lo haz probado x veces.

Soluciones:

Debes de destruir `$_SESSION["id_usuario"]` en tu código en alguna parte (*lógica*), ej.

```
// Destruir todas las variables de sesión.
$_SESSION = [];
// Destruir la sesión.
session_destroy();
```

Más info sobre [Destruir toda la información registrada de una sesión](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-destroy.php)

Chequear `$_SESSION["id_usuario"]` con `empty()` y (por ejemplo) si es numérico:

```
if ( empty($_SESSION["id_usuario"]) || (boolean) !is_numeric($_SESSION["id_usuario"] ) ) {

    header("Location: index1.php");
}
```

`empty()` es equivalente a:

```
!isset($variable) || $variable == false
```

Más info sobre [¿Como y cuando se usan isset() y empty() correctamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32133/como-y-cuando-se-usan-isset-y-empty-correctamente/32134#32134)

Y por último, limpiando el cache de tu navegador, también destruye la sesión.

Comment: Pues me alegro @Strider... borra todos los comentarios... que tengas un buen día noche! saludos